# Tasker Shortcut Icons & Names Revert Back to Default After Every Reboot

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, root-access, 4.3-jelly-bean, tasker, app-icons

All my custom Tasker shortcut icons get changed to the default Tasker icon and all the shortcuts' names got renamed to "Tasker" after every reboot no matter how many times I got them changed.

I have a rooted S3 running on Android 4.3 TouchWiz.

What should I do to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what Google tells me, this appears to be a TouchWiz issue. Try a different launcher and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I found similar answers on Google too and was hoping that there could be a fix rather than using other launcher. At least now I can have peace of mind knowing that it is TouchWiz's problem. Thanks, Trebor.

Answer (score 1):

Is Tasker installed on the SD card? I've seen that issue with other apps where some resources don't load. Try moving to internal storage.

Comment: I never thought of that before, elconejito. Tasker was in internal storage all the time but all my downloaded Tasker icons were in SD card, I moved all the icons into internal storage. I've tried a few reboots and the icons seem to have stopped reverting back to default. Thanks for the tips, elconejito! Really made my day.

Comment: My friend, it went back to the default icons again after 8 hours. Couldn't rule out what might have caused it.

Comment: Sad to hear that. Have you tried running a logcat app in the background? Then when your icons disappear you get the fun of digging through the logs to see what may have tripped it. Your on a rooted S3, have you tried any custom ROMs that still use touchwiz?

Comment: I should prolly try to check out the logs. No, I haven't used any custom ROM for TouchWiz. Any suggestions other than CynogenMod? I've heard of AOKP-ish ROMs as well.

Comment: I don't know offhand of any Touchwiz ROMs (I'm an HTC or Nexus guy mostly). I would start over at XDA Forums and look in the area for your phone/carrier for ROMs with Touchwiz there should be several. If you want to go AOSP-ish, AOKP, OmniROM, Paranoid Android, Carbon, etc. But before you go the AOSP route I'd just use a custom launcher :)